# How Best to Write HTAccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have an URL

```
http://example.com/buildings/edit/index.php?f_id=2
```

How do I

1. Write `.htaccess` to change the URL to

   ```
   http://example.com/buildings/edit/
   ```

and

2. Where do I place the `.htaccess` file? In the topmost root directory or a subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. write `.htaccess` to change the URL to
>
>    ```
>     http://example.com/buildings/edit/
>    ```

You don't use `.htaccess` for this - unless you are changing an existing URL structure and the old URLs have been indexed or linked to / bookmarked. You "change" the URL in your application and use `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL back from `/buildings/edit/` to `/buildings/edit/index.php?f_id=2`.

However, there does not appear to be enough information in the requested URL to complete this rewrite, unless you hardcode the `?f_id=2` query string. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(buildings/edit/)$ /$1/index.php?f_id=2 [L]
```

> 2. Where do I place the `.htaccess` file? In the topmost root directory or a subfolder?

This can depend. But it is common to have just a single `.htaccess` in the document root. The directive above assumes this would go in the document root.